# PHP auto execution

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to execute a PHP script at the predefined time. For instance, how can I write a php script that will force that script to be run on March 24th, 2013 at 11:14am(even if the browser is closed). I heard about cron but it is not clear to me.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 3):

Indeed `cron` could be an answer to your question. It is a special program that is in Linux systems and runs defined programs/commands on given time or periodically. Look here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite troubling to do in PHP. I suggest you use something like Cron's Jobs to do this. Most cPanels have CronsJob on them, but if you don't take a look at this tutorial: http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Comment: Uh, you can write cron jobs in PHP.

Comment: like so: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/ but it's just as easy to do it with a control panel. I think the post needs to go a bit more in depth about cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at what is available to you in your hosting environment.  Linux/Unix with command line access?  Cron is probably your answer (http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/).  If you are using a windows server, Windows Scheduled Tasks will work (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).  If you have cPanel or something like it (a lot of hosting solutions use it), then you will have to check the documentation for how to schedule tasks.

I disagree with Racialz, PHP command line (CLI) is just fine for this kind of work, I have even done svn hooks in php before.  The best answer for what to use can often be what you are most comfortable with.